# ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in Controller#create Error in my Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Can I get some assistance with my code which is throwing an `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMistach` in my JobsController#create.

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (JobCategory(#70843392) expected, got "At Home" which is an instance of String(#20478408)):    
app/controllers/jobs_controller.rb:46:in `create'
```

I am posting data through the form

```
<%= form_for @job do |f| %>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 select">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Job Category</label>
        <%= f.collection_select :job_category, JobCategory.order(:job_category),
          :job_category, :job_category, include_blank: false, id: "job_category",
          prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 select">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Job Type</label>
        <%= f.grouped_collection_select :job_type, JobCategory.order(:job_category),
          :job_types, :job_category, :job_type_id, :job_type, id: "job_type",
          prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control"    %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 select">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Frequency</label>
        <%= f.select :recurrence, [["One Off", "One Off"], ["Daily", "Daily"],
          ["Weekly", "Weekly"], ["Bi-Monthly", "Bi-Monthly"],
          ["Once-Monthly", "Once-Monthly"]],
          id: "recurrence", prompt: "Select...", class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Post My Job", class: "btn btn-normal" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Schema for Job Model

```
  create_table "jobs", primary_key: "job_id", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "job_title"
    t.text "job_description"
    t.text "key_instructions"
    t.integer "budget"
    t.datetime "booking_date"
    t.string "recurrence"
    t.boolean "is_flexible"
    t.string "address"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "date_posted"
    t.datetime "date_ending"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "featured"
    t.boolean "premium"
    t.integer "job_category_id"
    t.integer "job_type_id"
    t.string "job_category"
    t.string "job_type"
    t.index ["job_category_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_job_category_id"
    t.index ["job_type_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_job_type_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_jobs_on_user_id"
  end
```

I am posting the data from my form into my job.rb model but in the process using job_category.rb models and job_type.rb associations for additional info. The three models are related as follows

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :job_category
  belongs_to :job_type
  has_many_attached :images

  validates :job_category, presence: true
  validates :job_type, presence: true
  validates :recurrence, presence: true    
end

class JobType < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_categories
  has_many :jobs

  #attr_accessible :job_type
  #validates :job_type, :presence => true
end

class JobCategory < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :job_types
  has_many :jobs

  #attr_accessible :job_category
  #validates :job_category, :presence => true    
end
```

Any tips on where I am going wrong would be useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've got in your question, you have two choices for job categories, (which should apply also to job types):
1) You can create a table `job_categories` and drop `job_category_id` and `job_category` from the `jobs` table. 
2) The simpler option, and the one I might recommend based on very little knowledge other than you seem to be relatively new to db design and Rails, is to get rid of the `JobCategory` class entirely, and get rid of the `belongs_to: job_category`. You can also drop `job_category_id` from the `jobs` table. If you do that the rest of our code looks like it should be pretty close to just working.

The associations and extra classes you've set up are really meant for cases where you've stored that additional data in separate tables, and you are telling ActiveRecord how that data is related. Here, because a job has just one category, which is really just a single string with no additional data associated, putting everything in one table is not a bad option.